# Filtering a report when the value contains a comma

Tags: reporting

I would like to filter a report using a list of accounts. Some of those account names contain commas, eg "Monster's, Inc.", so I end up looking for Accounts named "Monster's" and accounts named "Inc."

Is there an escape character I can use for commas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use quotes, just like you would in a normal CSV-style format:

> Account Name equals "Monster's, Inc.", Acme

Would match Monster's, Inc. or Acme.